# How to handle close button in AWT Frame

Tags: java, java-8, awt, java-2d

I am starting with some basic Java2D examples -specifically under AWT-, following first examples of book "Introduction to Computer Graphics Java2D/Java3D" I have written the following two classes, one as "main" class:

```java
package com.example.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

            MyChart terminal = new MyChart();
            terminal.setTitle("The first Java 2D program");
            terminal.setSize(350,80);
            terminal.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

And another one which extends AWT Frame:

```java
package com.example.test;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MyChart extends Frame {


        public void MyChart() {

            this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){  
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
                    dispose();  
                }  
            });

        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d =  (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawString("Hello world!", 30, 50);
        };


}
```

This generates the expected "Hello World" window on the screen, but when I click on close button (Windows 10), nothing happens. I am trying to figure out what I did wrong while adding the listener without success.

Any tip or suggestion even to further debug is welcomed.

I am under Java: 1.8.0_191 and Windows 10 as mentioned.

Comment: *"examples of book "Introduction to Computer Graphics Java2D/Java3D"* Do you mean [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781846288487)? It was written in 2008! Even if using an AWT component (e.g. a `Canvas`) as the game rendering surface, I would reccomend using Swing components for *everything* else. Or as seen in my copy/paste comment .. Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

You weren't calling the `MyChart` function in your main class.
below code is working fine.

```
public class Test {

        public static void main( String[] args ) {
            System.out.println("Terminal Group");
            MyChart terminal = new MyChart();
            terminal.MyChart();//I added this.
            terminal.setTitle("The first Java 2D program");
            terminal.setSize(350,80);
            terminal.setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class MyChart extends Frame {
        public void MyChart() {
            this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){  
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
               dispose();
               }  
            });

        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d =  (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawString("Hello world!", 30, 50);
        };
}
```

Comment: You do not need to call constructor, it must be executed when you instantiate an object from that class. Issue was that constructor included void.

Comment: He made method in class named `MYchart` and in the main class it is necessary to call that closing method to work that was the reason that his code wasn't working.
your approach is fine but doing the same by making method is also fine.

Comment: I think the approach of @M.E. is better. `MyChart` is clearly intended to be a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor definition was wrong, `void` was present and must be removed.

Original code (WRONG constructor, uses void):

```java
    public void MyChart() {

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){  
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
                dispose();  
            }  
        });

    }
```

Corrected code (without void):

```java
public MyChart() {

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){  
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
                dispose();  
            }  
        });

}
```

Comment: Oh .. well spotted! It took me a few moments to see where it had been removed even *with* your example. But perhaps explain *where* `void` was removed, and that it was removed because it turned a constructor into a method (that would not automatically be called).

Comment: I have modified the answer to reflect that. It was actually found while discussing the issue with a friend, he was going crazy on why the constructor was not being called.